# Understand input DTO validation when working with groups

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

please I'm facing a pretty strange issue when I'm trying to add a `number` to the `sum` attribute I have in my class model `Counter`, so when specifying the normalization group `add` in the `NotBlank` assertion it `doesn't work` only if I do remove the groups parameter from the `NotBlank` , in contrary to `Type` assertion when specifying the group it does work but when **removing** it it throws an exception!

Please find below my classes:
**Counter**:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * ...
 * @ApiResource(
 *    attributes={"maximum_items_per_page"=50},
 *    messenger="input",
 *    shortName="Counters",
 *    collectionOperations={},
 *    itemOperations={
 *        "remove_inventory_item"={
 *          "method"="PUT",
 *          "path"="/counter/{id}/add",
 *          "input"=CounterInput::class,
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"={"Default", "add"}},
 *          "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"Default", "add"}},
 *        },
 *    ...
 *    }
 * )
 *
 */ 
   class Counter
    {
       /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=255)
         */
        private int $sum = 0;
        ...
    }
```

**CounterInput**:

```
class CounterInput
{   
    ...
    
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ApiProperty(
 *     attributes={
 *         "swagger_context"={
 *             "type"="integer"
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type(type="int", groups={"add"})
 *
 * @Groups({"add"})
 */
    public $number;
    ...
}
```

Here is the exception it throws if I remove `groups={"add"}` from `@Assert\Type`:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
  "title": "An error occurred",
  "detail": "Message of type \"App\\CounterInput\" failed validation.",
  "trace": [
    {
      "namespace": "",
      "short_class": "",
      "class": "",
      "type": "",
      "function": "",
      "file": "/srv/vendor/symfony/messenger/Middleware/ValidationMiddleware.php",
      "line": 45,
      "args": []
    },
    ...
```

Does someone have an explanation to that behavior?!

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the **Serializer** groups and the **Validator** groups. The annotation `Groups` is only used by the Serializer (setting which property will be normalized/denormalized) while the validation groups in the contraints (the `groups` property) is used to select which constraint will be applied to the property. They are **not** connected by any way.

Also, the `Default` is not a special group in the **Serializer** but is in the **Validator**.

This should work better (note the `normalization_context` & `denormalization_context` has changed and a `validation_groups` appears):

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ApiResource(
 *    itemOperations={
 *        "remove_inventory_item"={
 *            "normalization_context"={"groups"={"counter:read"}},
 *            "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"counter:write"}},
 *            "validation_groups={"Default", "add"}
 *        },
 *    }
 * )
 */ 
class Counter
{
}
```

```php
class CounterInput
{   
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type(type="int", groups={"add"})
     *
     * @Groups({"counter:read", "counter:write"})
     */
    public $number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information you provided apreciate it ^^, but after applying the changes just as you suggested and added the `add` group to the `NotBlank` constraint to become: `@Assert\NotBlank(groups={"add"})` this constraint was "disabled" and not working anymore! do you have any explanation why is that?

Comment: I’ve mixed v3 and v2.6. The validation groups arg in the 2.6 annotation is named: “ validation_groups” instead of “validation_context[‘groups’]”, which explains why contraints is ignored. The non existing validation group, “add” group is ignored here. I‘ve updated my answer.